# how to manually install chromium for jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, screen-scraping, chromium

after running this string of code:

```
await r.html.arender()
```

I get the result:

```
[W:pyppeteer.chromium_downloader] start chromium download.
Download may take a few minutes.
```

After this i get a bunch of errors and it does not work,so,  how do i manually install chromium on jupyter? Is there any other way by which i can resolve this problem? Or do i just install chromium normally?

I would like to add that when installing anaconda, i added anaconda to my PATH var while installing, which was not the recommended option. The recommended option was to register anaconda as the default python. Is this why there is a problem?

edit: the errors:

```
Error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py in wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname)
    484             try:
--> 485                 cnx.do_handshake()
    486             except OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py in do_handshake(self)
   1933         result = _lib.SSL_do_handshake(self._ssl)
-> 1934         self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
   1935 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py in _raise_ssl_error(self, ssl, result)
   1670         else:
-> 1671             _raise_current_error()
   1672 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\_util.py in exception_from_error_queue(exception_type)
     53 
---> 54     raise exception_type(errors)
     55 

Error: [('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    671                 headers=headers,
--> 672                 chunked=chunked,
    673             )
```

Comment: and what are these errors?

Comment: it's a really long list of them:

Comment: i updated the question with the errors

Comment: what's r in r.html.arender()?

Comment: r = await session.get("https://www.reddit.com/")